# Cannot build with MRTK v2.0.0-RC1

Tags: c#, mrtk

I had tried to make builds of the scene examples of the new MRTK version 2.0.0-RC1 on Unity 2018.3.10f1 but every time with every example there's a build error which says:
The type or namespace name 'HandJointKind' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'HandMeshObserver' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'JointPose' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Where do I get the library for this namespaces?

Comment: Have the same issue, haven't solved yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687207/how-to-build-and-deploy-a-working-unity-app-with-mrtk-v2-rc-for-hololens-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These types are part of the upcoming UWP SDK version 18362.

Download 10.0.18362.1 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewSDK

In the Unity Build Settings window, change the Target SDK Version to 10.0.18362.0, and make sure that Minimum SDK is is 10.0.10240.0.

This got me past the issue listed here. Then I ran into errors while trying to build the resulting solution. I had to upgrade all projects to C# language version 7.2.