# How to build and deploy a working unity app with MRTK v2 RC for HoloLens 1?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

**The problem**
To sum up, both Unity and Visual Studio 2017 builds the project, deploys the project, but once opening the app, nothing appears, not even a Unity splash screen. However making the bloom gesture on HoloLens proved that the app is "open" and closable, but that's as far as it gets.

**What we tried**
Our deployment target is a HoloLens 1 running the latest OS for said device (10.0.17763.380). 
We went through the provided solution here: 
[MRTK (V2) Need to update Hololens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616928/mrtk-v2-need-to-update-hololens)

As can be seen in below image: 

**NOTE: Images below shows Visual Studio 2019, but we tested both cases with Visual Studio 2017 AND Visual Studio 2019.**
[image: build settings]

We installed the Windows 10 Insider Preview SDK (Pardon the Danish)
[image: win18362sdk]

And tried to follow the solution provided here:
[Cannot build with MRTK v2.0.0-RC1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55544730/cannot-build-with-mrtk-v2-0-0-rc1)

Which seems to conflict with what the other answer to the problem seemed to be.
[image: win18362sdk2]
This solution-attempt however provided another error, saying that the deployment target (HoloLens 1) had to run OS 10.0.18326, which makes sense as this OS does not exist for this particular device as far as we know. We're as previously mentioned, running on the latest OS which is 10.0.17763.
As far as changing the C# language to 7.2, we had troubles dealing with that as all guides says to access the language from **Build** in the **Solution Properties** but we were unable to find this tab. Here's what happens when we attempt to press "Properties" after right-clicking the projectname.sln in the Visual Studio hierarchy:

[image: builttab]

However, we hoped we could change the language settings as in here:
[image: builttab]

but as you can see, there's no "Build" tab, and what we see looks a bit far from what we're suggested should be shown.

**What we hoped for**
A working HoloLens 1 app that can be opened up, like with the MRTK v2 Beta version.

**What actually happens**
As mentioned in the problem, the app gets built and deployed, but not only is it filled with errors, nothing appears on opening the built app.

---

Unity errors can be seen here:

```
Reference rewriter: Error: field `System.Numerics.Vector3 Windows.Perception.People.HandMeshVertex::Position` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsMixedReality.dll at System.Void Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.Input.WindowsMixedRealityArticulatedHand::UpdateControllerData(UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input.InteractionSourceState).
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
PostProcessWinRT:RunReferenceRewriter() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:1064)
PostProcessWinRT:Process() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:217)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Reference rewriter: Error: field `System.Numerics.Vector3 Windows.Perception.People.HandMeshVertex::Position` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsMixedReality.dll at System.Void Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.Input.WindowsMixedRealityArticulatedHand::UpdateControllerData(UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input.InteractionSourceState).
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
PostProcessWinRT:RunReferenceRewriter() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:1064)
PostProcessWinRT:Process() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:217)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Reference rewriter: Error: field `System.Numerics.Vector3 Windows.Perception.People.HandMeshVertex::Normal` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsMixedReality.dll at System.Void Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.Input.WindowsMixedRealityArticulatedHand::UpdateControllerData(UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input.InteractionSourceState).
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
PostProcessWinRT:RunReferenceRewriter() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:1064)
PostProcessWinRT:Process() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:217)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Reference rewriter: Error: field `System.Numerics.Quaternion Windows.Perception.People.JointPose::Orientation` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsMixedReality.dll at System.Void Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.Input.WindowsMixedRealityArticulatedHand::UpdateControllerData(UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input.InteractionSourceState).
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
PostProcessWinRT:RunReferenceRewriter() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:1064)
PostProcessWinRT:Process() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:217)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Reference rewriter: Error: field `System.Numerics.Vector3 Windows.Perception.People.JointPose::Position` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsMixedReality.dll at System.Void Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.Input.WindowsMixedRealityArticulatedHand::UpdateControllerData(UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input.InteractionSourceState).
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
PostProcessWinRT:RunReferenceRewriter() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:1064)
PostProcessWinRT:Process() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:217)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Reference rewriter: Error: field `System.Numerics.Vector3 Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialRay::Origin` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsMixedReality.dll at System.Void Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.Input.WindowsMixedRealityEyeGazeDataProvider::Update().
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
PostProcessWinRT:RunReferenceRewriter() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:1064)
PostProcessWinRT:Process() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:217)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Reference rewriter: Error: field `System.Numerics.Vector3 Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialRay::Direction` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsMixedReality.dll at System.Void Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.Input.WindowsMixedRealityEyeGazeDataProvider::Update().
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
PostProcessWinRT:RunReferenceRewriter() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:1064)
PostProcessWinRT:Process() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:217)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

```
Reference Rewriter found some errors while running with command "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.Analytics.DataPrivacy.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities.Gltf.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Services.TeleportSystem.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Services.SpatialAwarenessSystem.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Services.InputSystem.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Services.DiagnosticsSystem.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Services.BoundarySystem.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.SDK.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsMixedReality.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Extensions.PhotoCapture.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Extensions.Experimental.SpectatorView.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Extensions.Experimental.Sharing.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Extensions.Experimental.ScreenRecording.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Extensions.Experimental.MarkerDetection.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Core.Utilities.Async.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsVoiceInput.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.Subsystem.Registration.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.TextMeshPro.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.XR.ARExtensions.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.XR.WindowsMR.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.XR.FaceSubsystem.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.XR.ARFoundation.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.Timeline.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.SpatialTracking.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.Analytics.Tracker.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.Analytics.StandardEvents.dll" "--additionalreferences=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\X86,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\X64,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\x86,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\x86,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\x86,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\X64,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\ARM,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\X86,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\X64,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\X86,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\X64,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\X86,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\x86,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\x86,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\x86,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\x86,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\x86" "--platform=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.18362.0\Facade\Windows.winmd" "--dbg=pdb" "--framework=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed" "--alt=Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles,mscorlib;System,mscorlib;System,System;System,System.ComponentModel.Composition;System,System.Core;System.CodeDom.Compiler,System;System.Collections,mscorlib;System.Collections.Concurrent,mscorlib;System.Collections.Concurrent,System;System.Collections.Generic,mscorlib;System.Collections.Generic,System;System.Collections.Generic,System.Core;System.Collections.ObjectModel,mscorlib;System.Collections.ObjectModel,System;System.Collections.Specialized,System;System.ComponentModel,System;System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations,System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema,System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;System.Data,System.Data;System.Data.Common,System.Data;System.Diagnostics,mscorlib;System.Diagnostics,System;System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis,mscorlib;System.Diagnostics.Contracts,mscorlib;System.Diagnostics.Tracing,mscorlib;System.Dynamic,System.Core;System.Globalization,mscorlib;System.IO,mscorlib;System.IO,System;System.IO,System.Core;System.IO.Compression,System;System.IO.Compression,System.IO.Compression.FileSystem;System.IO.IsolatedStorage,mscorlib;System.Linq,System.Core;System.Linq.Expressions,System.Core;System.Net,System;System.Net.NetworkInformation,System;System.Net.Security,System;System.Net.Sockets,System;System.Numerics,System.Numerics;System.Reflection,mscorlib;System.Reflection.Emit,mscorlib;System.Resources,mscorlib;System.Runtime,mscorlib;System.Runtime.CompilerServices,mscorlib;System.Runtime.CompilerServices,System.Core;System.Runtime.ExceptionServices,mscorlib;System.Runtime.InteropServices,mscorlib;System.Runtime.InteropServices,System;System.Runtime.InteropServices,System.Core;System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes,mscorlib;System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes,System;System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime,mscorlib;System.Runtime.Serialization,mscorlib;System.Runtime.Serialization,System.Runtime.Serialization;System.Runtime.Serialization.Json,System.Runtime.Serialization;System.Runtime.Versioning,mscorlib;System.Runtime.Versioning,System;System.Security,mscorlib;System.Security.Authentication,System;System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection,System;System.Security.Claims,mscorlib;System.Security.Principal,mscorlib;System.Text,mscorlib;System.Text.RegularExpressions,System;System.Threading,mscorlib;System.Threading,System;System.Threading,System.Core;System.Threading.Tasks,mscorlib;System.Threading.Tasks,System.Core;System.Windows.Input,System;System.Xml,System.Runtime.Serialization;System.Xml,System.Xml;System.Xml.Linq,System.Xml.Linq;System.Xml.Schema,System.Xml;System.Xml.Serialization,System.Xml;<winmd>,Windows.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.AI.MachineLearning.MachineLearningContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.AI.MachineLearning.Preview.MachineLearningPreviewContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.Background.CallsBackgroundContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsPhoneContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsVoipContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.CommunicationBlocking.CommunicationBlockingContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.SocialInfo.SocialInfoContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTaskContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.Custom.CustomDeviceContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.DevicesLowLevelContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.Printers.PrintersContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardBackgroundTriggerContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardEmulatorContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Gaming.XboxLive.StorageApiContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Graphics.Printing3D.Printing3DContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Networking.Connectivity.WwanContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Networking.Sockets.ControlChannelTriggerContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Services.Maps.GuidanceContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Services.Maps.LocalSearchContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Services.Store.StoreContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Services.TargetedContent.TargetedContentContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.System.Profile.ProfileHardwareTokenContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.System.Profile.ProfileSharedModeContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.System.Profile.SystemManufacturers.SystemManufacturersContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.System.SystemManagementContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ViewManagementViewScalingContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.UI.Xaml.Core.Direct.XamlDirectContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivatedEventsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationCameraSettingsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ContactActivatedEventsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.WebUISearchActivatedEventsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundAlarmApplicationContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.LockScreenCallContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Preview.InkWorkspace.PreviewInkWorkspaceContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Preview.Notes.PreviewNotesContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Management.ResourceIndexerContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.Core.SearchCoreContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.ApplicationModel.Wallet.WalletContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.Portable.PortableDeviceContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.Printers.Extensions.ExtensionsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.Scanners.ScannerDeviceContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Devices.Sms.LegacySmsApiContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Gaming.Input.GamingInputPreviewContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Gaming.Preview.GamesEnumerationContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Gaming.UI.GameChatOverlayContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Gaming.UI.GamingUIProviderContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Globalization.GlobalizationJapanesePhoneticAnalyzerContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Management.Deployment.Preview.DeploymentPreviewContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Management.Workplace.WorkplaceSettingsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.AppBroadcasting.AppBroadcastingContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.AppRecording.AppRecordingContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.Capture.AppBroadcastContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.Capture.AppCaptureContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.Capture.AppCaptureMetadataContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.Capture.GameBarContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.Devices.CallControlContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.MediaControlContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.Playlists.PlaylistsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Media.Protection.ProtectionRenewalContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.LegacyNetworkOperatorsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Networking.XboxLive.XboxLiveSecureSocketsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Perception.Automation.Core.PerceptionAutomationCoreContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Security.EnterpriseData.EnterpriseDataContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Storage.Provider.CloudFilesContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.System.Profile.ProfileRetailInfoContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.System.UserProfile.UserProfileContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.System.UserProfile.UserProfileLockScreenContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.ApplicationsSettingsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.UI.Core.AnimationMetrics.AnimationMetricsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowDialogsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.UI.Shell.SecurityAppManagerContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting.HostingContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Web.Http.Diagnostics.HttpDiagnosticsContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Embedded.DeviceLockdown.DeviceLockdownContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorsFdnContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Phone.PhoneContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.Phone.StartScreen.DualSimTileContract.winmd;<winmd>,Windows.UI.WebUI.Core.WebUICommandBarContract.winmd" "--ignore=System.IConvertible,mscorlib".
Error: field `System.Numerics.Vector3 Windows.Perception.People.HandMeshVertex::Position` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsMixedReality.dll at System.Void Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.Input.WindowsMixedRealityArticulatedHand::UpdateControllerData(UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input.InteractionSourceState).
Error: field `System.Numerics.Vector3 Windows.Perception.People.HandMeshVertex::Position` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsMixedReality.dll at System.Void Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.Input.WindowsMixedRealityArticulatedHand::UpdateControllerData(UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input.InteractionSourceState).
Error: field `System.Numerics.Vector3 Windows.Perception.People.HandMeshVertex::Normal` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsMixedReality.dll at System.Void Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.Input.WindowsMixedRealityArticulatedHand::UpdateControllerData(UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input.InteractionSourceState).
Error: field `System.Numerics.Quaternion Windows.Perception.People.JointPose::Orientation` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsMixedReality.dll at System.Void Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.Input.WindowsMixedRealityArticulatedHand::UpdateControllerData(UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input.InteractionSourceState).
Error: field `System.Numerics.Vector3 Windows.Perception.People.JointPose::Position` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsMixedReality.dll at System.Void Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.Input.WindowsMixedRealityArticulatedHand::UpdateControllerData(UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input.InteractionSourceState).
Error: field `System.Numerics.Vector3 Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialRay::Origin` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsMixedReality.dll at System.Void Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.Input.WindowsMixedRealityEyeGazeDataProvider::Update().
Error: field `System.Numerics.Vector3 Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialRay::Direction` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsMixedReality.dll at System.Void Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.Input.WindowsMixedRealityEyeGazeDataProvider::Update().

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
PostProcessWinRT:RunReferenceRewriter() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:1062)
PostProcessWinRT:Process() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:217)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

---

Visual Studio 2017 errors can be seen here:

*(pasting this exceeds the stackoverflow limit of 30000 characters, so I'm providing a pastebin instead)*
https://pastebin.com/bx2QA2wL

Comment: Does it really need to be built as 32bit?

Comment: In order for SpectatorView in the MRTK to work (which we need), I'm quite sure x86 is a necessity

Comment: I think This Post can do the trick: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/55626479/10104036](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55626479/10104036)

Comment: Unfortunately, we already tried that. As you can see on the first image of build settings, minimum SDK is set to 10.0.10240. We also made sure to make it in a clean folder on each attempt with different built settings.

Comment: Thanks for the great question! I just updated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55544730/cannot-build-with-mrtk-v2-0-0-rc1 to mention that minimum SDK needs to be 10240, it is pending review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors starting with "Reference Rewriter" are benign and can safely be ignored, (tracked by [this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/3939)).

It's possible that your SampleScene that you are building is actually empty, in other words has no content. It may be a good idea to try instead to build and deploy the HandInteractionAllExample scene, located at *Assets\MixedRealityToolkit.Examples\Demos\HandTracking\Scenes\HandInteractionExamples.unity*.

Otherwise, your steps are looking correct. Please also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55626479/10104036) for instructions on how to build a UWP using MRTK v2.

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable **WSA Holographic Remoting Supported** flag under `Project Settings` > `Player` > `Universal Windows Platform settings` > `XR Settings`.

With that option enabled, the scene is loaded successfully but is not shown on the screen.